# Programmatically close a native application from another application

Tags: java, android, native

Basically, what I want to do is to close another app not created by me from my app. I haven't been able to find a solution but have learned that this is something many critizise as being a bad solution in general.

I do believe I have a good reason. What I want to do is to have an app that can recieve a file via PUSH OPP from another device that doesn't have an app installed on it. To be able to do this I have to disable the host-device's PUSH OPP application. I have to do this since I need to take over the default channel (12) for pushing files from the OS so that I have controll over the file-sending from the client. I can't use another channel since I can't have an app installed on the client and thus can't make it push the file via another channel. I know this probably is very bad practice but the device with the application will only be used for this specific application.

One way that seems to work is to manually disable the system's PUSH OPP application but this creates a hazzle when the user should install and use the app. They have to: 
1. Install the app. 
2. Every time they start the device they have to go into running applications and disable the standard PUSH OPP.
3. Run the app.

If I would be able to send a quit-command through my app to the native PUSH OPP app the default channel (12) would be freed up for me to use without the user having to go through step 2 every time. Is this even possible to do without root-access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your code, youcan use 
  system（“kill pid”）;
get pid from /proc